# How to write the data dynamically from Jsp to text file using servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to store the data from jsp page,which has many fields like
type of service
online
offline etc ,based on the selection it has to write the data to the file,

now I am able to  store statically where it is storing the selection value and null value for not selected values.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code what you have tried?

Comment: What is your question exactly? If the question is "how to write to files in Java", then google for that, or for "Java IO tutorial", and try things. The fact you're writing to a file from a servlet or not is irrelevant.

Comment: I am trying to write the  data into text file using servlet.

Answer (score 2):

i undestand what you are trying to say . find out the code . one `JSP` is used for Text field and another `JSP` is used for Storing input field value on text file .

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Please Sign My Guest Book!</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <CENTER>
        <H1>Please Sign My Guest Book!</H1>
        <FORM ACTION="basic.jsp" METHOD="POST">
            Your name:
            <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="TEXT1">
            <BR>
            <BR>
            <BR>
            Your comments:
            <BR>
            <TEXTAREA NAME="TEXTAREA1" ROWS="5" COLS="50"></TEXTAREA>
            <BR>
            <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit"><INPUT TYPE="RESET" VALUE="Reset">
        </FORM>
    </CENTER>
</BODY>
```

and For Storing Input Filed value on Text File .

```
  <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
 <HTML>
  <HEAD>   
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
      <H1>Thanks for Adding to the Guest Book!</H1>
     Here's what you and others have said:
    <BR>
    <BR>
       <%
          String name = request.getParameter("TEXT1");
          String text = request.getParameter("TEXTAREA1");
          String file = application.getRealPath("/") + "test.txt";
          FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
          filewriter.write("<B>Name: </B>" + name + "<BR>");
          filewriter.write("<B>Comments: </B><BR>");
          filewriter.write(text + "<BR><BR>");
          filewriter.close();
        %>
       <jsp:include page="ch15_04.txt" flush="true"/>
  </BODY>
```

Happy to Help Feel free to give your opinion .